# What's the best approach for server communication?

Tags: android, performance, http, tcp

My application communicate alot with a server - a lot of data is being sent and received.
My question is, should I really just use HttpConnection for all the requests or use some kind of TCP one? I read somewhere in the documentation (can't find it again) about something related to TCP, and that TCP IS more efficient in general.

I'm sending files of about 100-400kb on each server call.

I am also unsure about the server side effect of using one vs the other, on my server? I mean the app client may be working faster with HttpConnection, but is that more efficient for the server?
What would be the right approach to work with a server, in the long run, when not just a single call is being made?

I found little information about this topic, hope you guys can help me.

Comment: HTTP is served over a TCP connection. Manually dealing with sockets *might* get rid of a tiny bit of overhead, but this sounds like premature optimization at its worst.

Comment: Then http is the best approach for networking in android?

Comment: Describe how you are using your connection. Are you just sending over large blobs of data back and forth or something like IM.

Comment: Yes i'm sending files of about 100-400kb each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach would be to use either `HttpClient` or `URLConnection` classes. Of those two `HttpClient` is easier to use. If you discover those classes are somehow insufficient you will be using other things such as raw sockets  but it's unlikely.

Comment: Right. Thanks that's what i wanted to know.